# Coloring a truncated/trimmed part of a character

Tags: symbols, color, characters, crop, clip

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,graphicx}
\def\normala{a}

\def\trima{\rotatebox[origin=center]{25}{%
\clipbox{2.5pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{-25}{a}}}}

\begin{document}
a \trima % \trimcolora
\end{document}
```

My purpose is to make the cropped part of a character color. What I try to do

[image]

Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Shall we have a question about every bit of proofreading symbols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with rotating text and then rotating back is that the box surrounding the rotated text is bigger than the original box. So when you rotate back the new text is shifted. This is additionally complicated by the fact that `\clipbox` also changes the size of the box, so the clipped portion must be replaced with whitespace using a `\marginbox*` command (also from the `trimclip` package).

In this solution, a red character is rotated (clockwise), clipped (from the right), then rotated back. This happens inside an `\rlap` command so the black character that follows will overlap the red one. Then a black character is rotated, clipped (from the left), replaced with whitespace, and rotated back. This all happens inside a `\makebox` command whose width is that of the original character.

[image]

I left OP's 25 degree angle, but changed the clip size to `ex` units to it will adjust to the size of the text. You can adjust the `.55ex` (in three places) to your liking.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,graphicx}
\usepackage{color}% needed for \textcolor
\usepackage{calc}% needed for \widthof

\newcommand{\redtrim}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{#1}]{\rlap{%
    \rotatebox{25}{\clipbox*{0pt {-\depth} {.55ex} {\height}}%
    {\rotatebox{-25}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}}}%
    \rotatebox{25}{\marginbox*{.55ex 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\clipbox{.55ex 0pt 0pt 0pt}%
    {\rotatebox{-25}{{#1}}}}%
    }}}

\begin{document}
{\scriptsize a\redtrim{a}\redtrim{b}\redtrim{c}\redtrim{d}e}

a\redtrim{a}\redtrim{b}\redtrim{c}\redtrim{d}e

{\Large a\redtrim{a}\redtrim{b}\redtrim{c}\redtrim{d}e}
\end{document}
```

Adjusting the first `.55ex` (the one after `{-\depth}`) can give you a break between the red and black, or a slight overlap. The following three characters are produced using `.54ex`, `.55ex` and `.56ex` respectively.

[image]

Comment: It looks nice on paper. OP means?

Comment: "Original Poster".  You in this case. :)

Comment: Your informative explanations were good. Well, can it be that? red "a" is done first. This red "a" is cut below 25 degrees. Then black "a" is made. This black "a" is cut 25 degrees above. Eventually these two are merged from the cut-off points.

Comment: Is there a reason? The output would look the same.

Comment: Yes, the output would look the same. But very little red color appears under the character. Like @samcarter's solution.

Comment: I edited my answer to solve this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69683/discussion-between-sandy-g-and-ozgur).

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{trimclip,graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\normala{a}

\def\trima{%
    \raisebox{0.02em}{\textcolor{red}{a}}\hskip-0.435em%
    \rotatebox[origin=center]{25}{%
\clipbox{2.5pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{-25}{a}}}}

\begin{document}
a \trima % \trimcolora
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the positioning adjustment here is done manually, the solution won't work for other letters or other sizes.

Comment: I understood. Your code taught me new information.